# Camera (AVFoundation new APIs) classes for iOS 10 does not found

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, ios10

I am facing the error: No known method for selector

> defaultDeviceWithDeviceType:mediaType:position:

While documentation for this method is given at:
[AVCap](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/2361508-defaultdevicewithdevicetype)

When I call this method, it shows error that method not found. My code is:

```
AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithDeviceType: AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInDuoCamera
                                            mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo
                                             position: AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
```

Here are all the version details:
MacOS: 10.11.5,
xCode: 8.0 beta,
iOS: 10.0.1

Answer (score 2):

> The `AVCaptureDevice` methods `devices` and `devicesWithMediaType:` are deprecated in `iOS 10`, and do not provide access to the dual camera or telephoto camera.
>
> When you use the AVCaptureDevice class for video or photo capture, you
>   can choose to use the dual camera device to gain these features, or to
>   specifically use only the wide-angle or telephoto camera for more
>   manual control.

To access capture devices in iOS 10.0 and later, you can use either of the following methods:

Call the `defaultDeviceWithDeviceType:mediaType:position:` method. (Pass the `AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInDuoCamera` device type to access the dual camera.

That call returns nil for devices without a dual camera—in that case, you can call the same method again, passing the `AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInWideAngleCamera` device type, to obtain the default back camera.)

Create an `AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession` object, passing the device attributes you want to use for capture, and enumerate its devices list to select a device for your capture session.

read docs here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017084-DontLinkElementID_11

Comment: Thank you @Ronak for your time. I have already gone through the documentation several times and understand new changes. My problem is when i call the method 'defaultDeviceWithDeviceType:mediaType:position:' it show error that this method does not found in class 'AVCaptureDevice'.

Answer (score 0):

When I switched from xCode 8.0 beta to release version xCode 8.0 then it worked.Thanks